# Special characters in YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, special-characters, yaml, kaminari

In a css.sass file, I have an arrow character that is displayed through an li:

```
.fi-arrow-right:before
  content: "\f10b"
```

I need to get this same image into a YML config file to change the way kaminari buttons look.  How would I represent this character in YML?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out this was the wrong way to go about solving this issue, I had to alter the kaminari next_page view